# IBOutlet that conforms to a protocol?

Tags: swift, swift2

In appears that in Swift you cannot create an IBOutlet that conforms to a protocol. My current work around is creating an IBOutlet of type AnyObject and a variable that conforms to my protocol and then setting said variable to the outlet in awakeFromNib() like so:

```
@IBOutlet private var fooOutlet: AnyObject!
private var foo: FooProtocol!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    foo = fooOutlet as? FooProtocol
}
```

My question is: Is there a better way to accomplish this ? or is this the only way that this can be accomplished in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
@objc(FooProtocol)
protocol FooProtocol {}
```